# Angular controller to handle showing or hiding multiple widgets

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have 7 variables controlling 7 widgets showing or hiding from the frontend. I want to put them together and control all of them using one function. Here is what I have. However, I feel like even though this way works, the code is really ugly and should have space for improvements.

```
$scope.showWidget = function(showA, showB, showC, showD, showE, showF, showG) {
                    if (showA !== null) {
                        $scope.showshowA = showA;
                    }
                    if (showB !== null) {
                        $scope.showshowB = showB;
                    }
                    if (showC !== null) {
                        $scope.showshowC = showC;
                    }
                    if (showD !== null) {
                        $scope.showD = showD;
                    }
                    if (showE !== null) {
                        $scope.showshowE = showE;
                    }
                    if (showF !== null) {
                        $scope.showshowF = showF;
                    }
                    if (showG !== null) {
                        $scope.showG = showG;
                    }
                }
```

E.G. I will use the following code snippet for controlling showG variable on the fly.

```
 $scope.showWidget(null, null, null, null, null, null, true);
```

Comment: How is a widget shown?

Comment: @Tony A widget is shown by setting showX to true. Thanks!

Comment: so you have ng-show based on the showshowX variables?

Comment: @Tony. Yes. I do.

Comment: The code in your question is sketchy, to the point of being nearly hypothetical. A real working example would make this code more reviewable. (Press Ctrl-M in the question editor to make a live example.)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your ng-show to use a function:

```
ng-show="isShown('widgetX')" ng-click="toggleWidget('widgetX')"
```

And then in your controller:

```
var widgets = {
    widgetA: {
        shown: true
    },
    widgetB: {
        shown: true
    },
    ...
};

$scope.isShown = function(widgetID) {
    return widgets[widgetID].shown;
}

$scope.toggleWidget = function(widgetID) {
    widgets[widgetID].shown = !widgets[widgetID].shown;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tony first. The thing is actually a little bit different. Those variables(showA to showG) are not controlled by one ng-show. They have different ng-show(s) and are controlled by different buttons/input boxes separately..

Comment: Yeah I figured @catlovespurple - you would need to have an ng-show and ng-click for each widget with the appropriate ID ('widgetA' to 'widgetG') and have them in the $scope widgets object; or you could perhaps use ng-repeat with the populated widgets object to create your widgets

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you mean. In terms  of if(newA!==null){a = newA;} do you have any suggestions on short-hand version ?

Comment: @catlovespurple this approach would negate the need for that bit of code as the controller is storing the shown state of each widget, and you are merely passing a (known) widget ID